# Using 'N in ADO.recordset.filter string

Tags: unicode, vb6, ado, recordset

I have a VB6 ADO recordest that contains unicode text and need to filter it using .filter method with unicode text. I tried to use N' function but it does not work when I use it in .Filter text

```
Rs.filter = "Name = 'Apple'"  'OK

Rs.Filter = "Name = N'英語'"  'Not working for filter text
```

How I should wrap the text or I need to use another function?

Comment: Do you happen to get an error?

Comment: What's type of DB that recordset reads from? Ms Access, MS SQL Server, other? It might be easier to filter it right there when retrieving the data for the RS.

Comment: @HelO'Ween It is MS SQL server. the legacy code used the recordset filter and I should follow that or make a big update that is not possible now.

Comment: @BrianMStafford yes I get an error message.

Comment: What message do you get?  Adding it to your question would be very useful.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Comment: @Al007 Did you try without the N?